# iOS: touch events are not sent to the next controller while a modal is dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my `Storyboard` I defined a `modal segue`. The corresponding modal view is dismissed via a button and a simple:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        return;
    }];   
}
```

Everything works but the thing is, while this transition is occurring, if the user taps in the view of the "next" controller (i.e. the one that will replace the modal), touch events are not captured by this controller until the transition completes entirely.

My chain of controllers is:

```
UINavigationController -> visibleViewController -> modal Controller
```

(but note that the `modal Controller` is actually presented by the `navigationController` - that's how it is setup by default in the Storyboard).

How can you make sure that as soon as the transition starts, touch events are sent to the next controller?

Comment: can you show your storyboard please?

Comment: @Mikael I am not sure why this question popped up last week: I asked it more than a year ago... I don't have this code anymore unfortunately, and I can't remember how I ended up solving or mitigating the problem.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is normal iOS behavior and not Model `ViewController` specific. Entering or exiting `ViewController`s using push and pop will also wait for transition to end before receiving touch events on the destination `ViewController`.

A good solution to avoid this would be to present your `ViewController` in a container inside the first `ViewController`. 
Showing and dismissing the `ViewController` are under your responsibility and will require a bit more code (for example playing with the alpha channel of the container) but will give you more control on who and when a view receives touch events.

For example:

```
- (IBAction)hideContainer:(id)sender {   

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                          delay:0.0         
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^
                             {
                                 self.container.alpha = 0;
                             }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present or dismiss some view controller modally, during transitions your modal view controller's view is added by system onto transitioning view.

During dismissal, view controller which was under your modal one, is covered by a transparent transitioning view which intercepts touches, so basically there is no simple way to pass them through it.

The option could be that you override the `transitioningDelegate` for your modal presentation, and add some intercepting view onto the transitioning view under your modal controller's view. Intercepting view will get all your touches during transition and then you will forward them to the underlying presenting view controller's view.

e.g. during dismissal transition you would have something like this:

```
Modal VC View
----------------
Intercepting View
--------------------------
Transitioning View
-------------------------------------------
Presenting View Controller's view
------------------------------------------------------------------
Window
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then you theoretically will be able to forward your touches to the Presenting View Controller's view.